# Trying to detect when graph first changes direction

Tags: change-point, gradient

Trying to identify when the point where graph trend changes, the first time it changes, circled in the picture. Any ideas? Prior to the point we want, the graph can be either flat, decreasing or increasing, but after this point we wish to find the graph must be increasing. Tried using changepoint, but I have multiple points on the graph which I need to detect, and the range of each graph is different in every point by quite a lot. 
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Have you explored the threads linked through the [tag:change-point] tag?

Comment: Do you want to model these as random effects around a general change point (all data in the same model) or on a line-by-line basis? The `mcp` package in `R` should handle this OK, and I can write an answer.